# In c, Is it bad to have functions dedicated to allocate memory?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

In a c project which strategy is the best when allocating memory inside functions

For example, I got this struct:

```
  typedef struct t_example{
    int x;
    int y;
  }example;
```

I have created a function that initialize an instance:

```
  /**
   return value must be freed
   */
  example * example_init(){
    example *p_example = malloc(sizeof(example));
    p_example->x = 42;
    p_example->y = 42;
    return p_example;
  }
```

And I can call this function like this

```
example *p_example = example_init();
```

but as my project grow I found that sometimes I don't need to allocate memory if I just need a local variable on the stack, but need to initialize it, so I changed the init function to this:

```
  void example_init(example *p_example){
    p_example->x = 42;
    p_example->y = 42;
  }
```

so I can call this function like this

```
example o_example;
example_init(&o_example);
```

of course this same function also work in case I have a pointer

```
example *p_example = malloc(sizeof(example));
example_init(p_example);
```

My question is: which is the best practice :

1. to offer a function that will allocate memory (and properly document this) as it may be convenient in come cases, or 2) this should it be left to the caller of the function.

I also read that the std function do not allocate memory dynamically, and that's why the strdup function is not standard. So I would say that the second option is the best ?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have functions allocating memory, but it is better to be reflected in their name, and have the appropriate de-allocation routines coupled.

Comment: First of all, `example_init(p_example)` should be `p_example= example_init(p_example);`

Comment: I would say in the third code snippet you are calling the allocator function incorrectly. Should be `example *p_example = example_init();`

Comment: ... the argument is not defined or used.

Comment: @TheDrev Weather Vane is right here ^

Comment: I would suggest `p_example = example_make();` or  `p_example = example_create(42, 65);` ; *initialization* don't create something, but put in good initial state some already existing memory. Your code is good, but the `example_init` is IMHO a poor name

Comment: It's not bad to have functions that allocate memory. It _is_ bad forgetting to check the return value of the allocation before proceeding, regardless of whether you do the allocation in a dedicated function or not. As long as your functions are well documented, they can do anything they want.

Comment: Don't assume that there is some kind of rationale behind which functions that reside in the C standard library. My personal theory is that Richie & friends wrote down all functions present in 1970s Unix on bits of paper, put them in a hat and then randomly picked 100 or so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is: which is the best practice : 1) to offer a function that will allocate memory (and properly document this) as it may be convenient in come cases, or 2) this should it be left to the caller of the function.

I don't think this is a matter of best practices.  There is nothing inherently wrong with a function that creates and returns (a pointer to) a new, dynamically-allocated object.  For this to be more useful than allocating space directly, such a function should be sure to give the object a consistent initial value as well, though it might well do so by calling a different function.  Overall, this is the C analog of C++'s `new` operator combined with a constructor.

That is not exclusive of provision for users to allocate objects themselves, whether dynamically or otherwise.  If the type in question is public, then there may be good reason to provide an initialization function that does no allocation.  As you observe, that particularly serves the purposes of code that relies on automatically or statically allocated objects.

> I also read that the std function do not allocate memory dynamically, and that's why the strdup function is not standard. So I would say that the second option is the best ?

The Standard committee's policy for standard library functions cannot rationally be extended to your own functions.  The ultimate outcome would be that no function anywhere should ever allocate memory dynamically, and if that were the committee's intent, then they would have at least deprecated the standard library's explicit memory allocation functions.

Answer (score 5):

It's always a good idea to abstract allocation, deallocation, and initialization into their own functions when dealing with non-scalar types.  It's especially useful when you have to allocate and deallocate multiple resources in a specific order.

Use separate functions for allocation and initialization:

```
example *example_create( void ) 
{
  example *p = malloc( sizeof *p );
  if ( !p )
    log_error(); // or not - up to you
  return p;
}

void example_init( example *p )
{
  p->x = p->y = 42;
}

example *new_example = example_create( );
if ( new_example )
  example_init( new_example );
```

For some added flexibility, you can pass the initializer as a *callback* to the allocator:

```
example *example_create( void (*example_initializer)(example *) )
{
  example *p = malloc( sizeof *p );
  if ( p )
    if ( example_initializer )
      example_initializer( p );
  return p;
}
```

This way you can combine allocation and initialization into a single operation, but still keep allocation and initialization *decoupled* from each other:

```
void init42( example *p ) { p->x = p->y = 42; }
void init0( example *p ) { p->x = p->y = 0; }
void initRand( example *p ) { p->x = rand(); p->y = rand(); }

example *p42 = example_create( init42 );
example *p0  = example_create( init0 );
example *pRand = example_create( initRand );
```

And, you can still use the initializer with `auto` variables:

```
example instance42;
init42( &instance42 );

example instance0;
init0 ( &instance0 );

example instanceRand;
initRand( &instanceRand );
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a very good question, there are many things to consider here. The following things are good design/good practice:

1. Private encapsulation of data.
2. Keeping allocation separate from algorithms.
3. Avoiding a tight coupling between a class/ADT and its allocation method.

None of the above is subjective, these are all universally regarded as good design.

In C, it is very hard to get all of these at once. For simple applications, it is usually fine to skip some of the above. For larger, complex applications, you'll definitely want 1).

- Your first example `example * example_init()` sates 2) - keeping initialization and allocation together is fine design-wise. But it doesn't sate 3). And probably it does not sate 1) either, unless you implemented this struct as an *opaque type*.
- You second example `void example_init(example *p_example)` sates 2) and 3), but probably not 1).

  You can rewrite the second example to sate all three, but then you end up with two functions. It is awkward for the user of your code to call both an allocation function and an initialization function - that's not ideal API design.

Opaque type on the other hand, is often regarded as the very best design practice in C - it is the only way to get true private encapsulation in C while keeping the code re-entrant. But when you use opaque type, the caller can no longer do the allocation. And therefore you can almost never have 3) when you use opaque type.

For hosted systems where you have an OS, dynamic allocation is usually the de facto standard allocation and there it is not a problem to always use dynamic allocation, 3) is not much of an issue. On a freestanding embedded system however, dynamic allocation is banned, so if you tie your code up with dynamic allocation it will not be suitable for embedded systems.

So the answer to your question is: it depends.

If your program already doesn't have much in the way of private encapsulation, then leaving the allocation to the caller is definitely the best way to go. But then on the other hand, lacking private encapsulation could be a major design flaw.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, only have a function that allocates memory if the memory allocation is complex (e.g. your struct contains pointers which need to be allocated). In such a case have a symmetric function that de-allocates as well. Libraries like cairo and openSSL have this kind of pattern.

Otherwise let the user decide how to create the struct (either use malloc or create it on the stack).

If you have a create function always have a symmetric destroy function since this communicates to the user that he must destroy the object himself. It also ensures that the correct heap is used for the deallocation (dlls/so may have their own heap).